# css float and alignment not working

Tags: html, css

My current work is shown below. What I would like to achieve is that the text `Membership Registration` is aligned center, while the hyperlinks `English` and `中 文` is floating right but close to border-bottom - Now they are floating to the top.

[image]

HTML:

```
<div id="Header">
     <a id="logo" href="http://localhost"><img alt="logo" src="images/logo.jpg"/></a>
     <div id="HeaderText"><h1>Membership Registration</h1></div>
     <div id="header_right">
       <a href="index.php?lang=en">English</a> |
       <a href="index.php?lang=zh">中文</a>
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#Header {
   height:70px;
   margin-bottom:11px;
   border-bottom: #dbe0e3 1px solid;
}

#header_right {
   float: right;
   padding-right: 50px;
}

#logo {
   float: left;
   height:65px;
   left:20px;
   top:17px;
}

img {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
   max-height: 100%;
   max-width: 100%;
}

#HeaderText {
   float: left;
   text-height: 65px;
   text-align: center;
   left: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add padding-top to `#header-right`.

```
#header_right {padding-top: 30px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e67wd21v/1/

Note to your code:
`left` and `top` do nothing when the element has no `position` property (`#logo`)
`text-height` property doesn't exist (used at `#headerText`) - you probably meant `height` or `line-height`.

Answer (score 0):

update css for header_right

```
#header_right {
float: right;
padding:30px 50px 0 0;
box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

check fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/swapnilmotewar/sh72pgmx/1/